# Install therubyracer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Решил попробовать ruby on rails. Встала необходимость использовать gem 'therubyracer' но никак не могу его установить. Перерыл кучу форумов - ничего до сих пор не помогло. Ругается вроде на libv8

Comment: Есть какие-то особые причины использовать именно этот гем? Потому что рельсовый [`execjs`](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs) должен спокойно обнаруживать NodeJS и даже JScript из Windows, что для рантайма JavaScript вполне годится.

Answer (score 3):

Установите `libv8` используя следующую команду

`gem install libv8 -- --with-system-v8`

[Вот почему](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577759/installing-libv8-gem-on-mavericks)